# for loop misses the first iteration

Tags: python, list

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

new_trace=[1,2,2,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,3,4,3,5,6,4,7,6,5,4,5,4,6,6,5,6,4,4,5,6,7,7,6,5,5,7,6,5]

def extractIntervals(new_trace):
    listofAppearances=[[new_trace[0]],[0],[-1]]
    for i in range(0,len(new_trace)-1,1):
        if new_trace[i] in listofAppearances[0]:
            continue
        else:
            listofAppearances[0].append(new_trace[i])
            listofAppearances[1].append(i)
            listofAppearances[2].append(-1)
    print(listofAppearances)

    for j in range(len(new_trace)-1,0,-1):
        for k in range(0,len(listofAppearances[0])-1,1):
            if (new_trace[j]==listofAppearances[0][k]) and (listofAppearances[2][k]==-1):
                listofAppearances[2][k]=j
            else:
                continue

    print(listofAppearances)

def main():
    extractLivenessIntervals(new_trace)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

In my code above I am trying to extract Intervals of appearance (delimited by 1st and last appearance indexes of every number in the list) The way I do it is I parse once the list and if the number still doesn't exist in **listOfAppearances**, then I append it to first column, the index to the second column and I set the 3rd column to **-1**.

I parse again the list in reverse every element is look for in the **listofAppearances** and the corresponding 3rd column is changed to the current index if still set to -1.

This works, but the first iteration when parsing the list backward has some issue that I can't figure out. the result I have with this example of a list is:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 3, 6, 13, 14, 16], [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 1, 3, 6, 13, 14, 16], [9, 8, 12, 27, 37, 36, -1]]
```

As you can see the last element of the second list is still set to -1 which I don't understand why! I inspected every inch of the code and I can't see why is it this way!

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
for k in range(0, len(listofAppearances[0])-1, 1):
```

to

```
for k in range(0, len(listofAppearances[0]), 1):
```

in line 17.

---

**Edit:** you can get the same result by:

```
def extractIntervals(new_trace):
    listofAppearances = [0, 0, 0]
    listofAppearances[0] = list(set(new_trace))
    # returns new_trace without repeated elements

    listofAppearances[1] = [new_trace.index(i) for i in list(set(new_trace))]
    # returns a list with the index of the first occurrence
    # in new_trace of each element in list(set(new_trace))

    listofAppearances[2] = [len(new_trace) - 1 - new_trace[::-1].index(i) for i in list(set(new_trace))]
    # returns a list with the index of the last occurrence
    # in new_trace of each element in list(set(new_trace))

    print(listofAppearances)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest processing a stream of values? First define a few helper functions, then use them to group each element with the positions at which it occurs.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


second = itemgetter(1)
first_and_last = itemgetter(0, -1)


def sort_and_group(seq, k):
    return groupby(sorted(seq, key=k), k)


def extract_intervals(new_trace):
    tmp1 = sort_and_group(enumerate(new_trace), second)
    tmp2 = [(val, *first_and_last([x for x,_ in positions])) for val, positions in tmp1]
    return zip(*tmp2)


new_trace=[1,2,2,3,2,1,4,3,2,1,3,4,3,5,6,4,7,6,5,4,5,4,6,6,5,6,4,4,5,6,7,7,6,5,5,7,6,5]

print(list(extract_intervals(new_trace)))
```

`tmp1` is a pairing of each element with the list of positions at which it occurs.

`tmp2` is a list of triples, consisting of a list element and the first and last position at which it occurs.

The call to `zip` "unzips" the list of triples into three tuples: the elements, the first positions, and the last positions.